# get text of feature and change it - openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to change the text of feature after setting style. I have a code like this below but I don't know how to get current color and text from it. I've used getStyle() function already.

```
this.setVectorStyle = (color, text) => {
  const style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 28,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: [255, 255, 255, 0.1] }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: color,
        width: 5
      })
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: text,
      scale: 1.3,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: "#fff"
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "0",
        width: 3
      })
    })
  })
  return [style];
}
...
iconFeature.setStyle(this.setVectorStyle(myColor, myText));
```

Comment: Take a look at getStyle() API : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#getStyle

Comment: @SachiTekina I've used getStyle() already. Maybe I can't use it properly

Comment: It would be helpful if you included it in your question.

Comment: @SachiTekina I've updated my question